# Problems moving whole project from one directory to another

Tags: civicrm

I have Xampp Portable installed on Windows 10.

I run about a dozen Drupal, Wordpress and other CMS on there. I can move the whole stack to different drives and machines and it all works perfectly, only one that can't work is D7/CIVICrm install.

When I move it to another directory I get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CRM_Core_ClassLoader in C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\ClassLoader.php on line 36
```

I can see that the path in the error is the wrong path.

The correct new path is:

```
G:\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4
```

And not:

```
C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\
```

As stated in error, where should I go change that setting? In what file/directory?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82221/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-vincent-problems-moving-whole-project-from-one).

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the path name in civicrm.settings.php from:

```
G:\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4
```

To

```
C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\
```

This is around LINE 180:

Code looks like this:

$civicrm_root = 'G:/August25/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', 'G:/August25/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4\sites\default\files\civicrm\templates_c\');
}

But the slashes also have to be forward like this "/", I searched from Windows path, that's why I couldn't find the code using find and replace!